# Docker Swarm GPU Resource Allocation Issue ("no suitable node" Error) - WSL2 & Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gpu, docker-swarm, wsl-2

I'm trying to deploy a service in Docker Swarm mode that utilizes a GPU, but I'm encountering a "no suitable node (insufficient resources on 1 node)" error

Included GPU resource reservation settings in the Docker Compose file.
Checked the node using docker node ls: There is only a single node (docker-desktop) in the Swarm cluster.
Confirmed GPU availability using nvidia-smi.
Added nvidia_gpu=true label to the node.
Set the number of replicas to 1, but the same error persists.
What additional steps can I take to resolve this issue?

Comment: it might help if enough of the stack file was included to show the constraints.